# How do I catch an imagick fatal error in PHP

Tags: php, imagick

i am using imagick to create thumbnails for pdf documents. i get a fatal error on this line..

```
$imagick->readImage($file .'[0]');
```

I tried wrapping in a try catch but as i learned that doesn't work because it's a fatal error, not an exception. How would I gracefully catch this error?

I am more concerned about using PHP to detect the error than solving the imagick problem, since any number of errors might come up with user pdf files. thanks!

Comment: What *is* the error?

Comment: @PeeHaa OP specifically says it does not matter.

Comment: @Marek what post are you reading?

Comment: @PeeHaa "more concerned about using PHP to detect the error than solving the imagick problem"

Comment: Read *the* problem. Not just any random problem. You cannot just go out blindly trying to handle unknown errors. Nor can anybody reasonably give an answer without crucial information

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to catch fatal errors in php. This is given. There are still couple of things you can do:

1. Function registered using `register_shutdown_function()` is still executed. You can put your error hadling into such function, and if the `readImage()` succeeds, register empty function.
2. You can put thumbnail generation into php command line script and execute it using `exec('php thngenerate.php ' . escapeshellarg($file .'[0]'), $out, $return_var);`. If `$return_var != 0`, there was an error.
3. Similar to #2, but script is called using http, this time you watch for internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

It should show up in the server error logs which can give you insight into why it fails and hopefully prevent it from happening in the first place.  Other than that, it depends on what you are trying to do.  I use mine for resizing images and creating thumbnails so my checks are related to that; does imagick show the correct dimensions and is the thumbnail present and have a file size greater than 0.

Answer (score -1):

You can set your custom error handler with [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php):

```
function exceptionErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {    
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}

set_error_handler("exceptionErrorHandler");
```