# Handling unknown images with imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

As people have already found, when attempting to load a file into Imagick that it cannot handle for whatever reason, it will throw an exception that cannot be caught.

I created an ICO file and attempt to load it using readImageFile():

```
$image = new imagick();
$handle = fopen('icon.ico', 'rb');
$image->readImageFile($handle);
```

This will throw:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501'
```

When I specify the image will be an ICO file, it works. So this code runs fine:

```
$image = new imagick();
$image->setFormat('ICO');
$handle = fopen('icon.ico', 'rb');
$image->readImageFile($handle);
```

Using readFile instead of readImageFile, it apparently looks at the extension, because this code also runs fine:

```
$image = new imagick();
$image->readimage('icon.ico');
```

However, when I rename the ICO file to icon.jpg and run this:

```
$image = new imagick();
$image->readimage('icon.jpg');
```

It fails with the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00 `icon.jpg' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/322'
```

The following code, however, handles the ICO file renamed to icon.jpg fine:

```
$image = new imagick();
$image->setFormat('ICO');
$handle = fopen('icon.jpg', 'rb');
$image->readImageFile($handle);
```

Obviously the best way to handle images is to not look at the extension, which could be anything, but look at the actual file. Imagick apparently fails to do this. We have PHP functions such as mime_content_type(), getimagesize() and finfo_buffer() (which PHP.net recommends I think). But they will return something like "image/x-icon", which the setFormat() function will not take.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

It's true that you can not trust the filename, but some file formats do not have a unique magic file signature, or have a vague identifier. When ImageMagick reads an image, it'll attempt to trust the magic signature FIRST, and fall-back to file extension if it can't resolve the image type.

As you've correctly discovered, reading an image from a file descriptor doesn't allow ImageMagick to fall-back on the file extension, and so you're responsible for telling `Imagick` about the format before calling `Imagick::readImageFile`.

> What would be the best way to go about this?

You have to be explicate about what's allowed. The built-in FileInfo methods `mime_content_type` & `finfo_buffer` are a good start (but not fool proof). But if you already of a file descriptor open, I would recommend "peeking" at the data...

```php
$filename = 'untrusted';
$handle = open($filename, 'rb');
// Allow the most common & modern formats to work as expected.
try {
   $image = new Imagick();
   // Pass original file name for IM fall-back
   $image->setFilename($filename);
   $image->readImageFile($handle);
// Attempt to handle specific formats.
} catch (ImagickException $e) {
   // Create new instance
   $image = new Imagick();
   // Rewind FD
   fseek($handle, 0);
   // Read first four bytes
   $peek = fread($handle, 4); 
   // Collect MIME-TYPE
   $mime = mime_content_type($filename); 
   // Explicitly allow KNOWN formats. (also see http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html)
   if ($mime == 'image/x-icon' && $peek == "\x00\x00\x01\x00") {
       $image->setFormat('ICO');
   } else if ($mime == 'image/x-icon' && $peek == "\x00\x00\x02\x00") {
       $image->setFormat('CUR');
   } else {
     // Error handle
   }
   fseek($handle, 0); // Rewind again.
   $image->readImageFile($handle);
}
```

YMMV, and I'm sure there's better PHP folks that can help.

Comment: Nice, Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately it's not just ICO files I need to allow, but a whole bunch. I convinced the client to compose a whitelist. I was hoping finfo_buffer was foolproof enough. Maintaining my own list of 4 byte signatures for a whole bunch of filetypes doesn't seem ideal. I just wished Imagick wouldn't fail so spectacularly whenever it cannot detect the proper filetype.

Comment: It might be time to reevaluate the solution architecture. You should make the effort to pass the original filename to `Imagick`. It's also very common for exceptions to raise, so the application should be able to expect & handle such.

Comment: I'm not sure I can trust the original filename, since I don't trust my users. As I understand from this question, when Imagemagick throws a fatal error, there is not much you can do to catch it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156447/how-do-i-catch-an-imagick-fatal-error-in-php

Comment: Try it. The fatal error is _not_ catching & handling the exception.

Comment: Thank your for bearing with me but I still don't understand. Imagemagick throws a fatal error. I can catch it and it'll execute everything I put in the catch block but after that it's over. No processing further images, or rendering a nice json output.